# Java: start a process on a remote machine via sshj, continue with programm and stop process afterwards (dstat)

Tags: java, linux, bash, ssh, sshj

I'm trying to run dstat on a remote machine via ssh from my Java program using the `sshj library`.

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.Session;
import net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.Session.Command;
```

What I need to do is start dstat on the remote machine (Linux), continue with my program to create some load on the remote machine (database server) and stop the `dstat` logging after that.

what I have done so far : 
connect to server, copy the dstat folder to `/tmp/dstat`, make files runnable and then:

```
session = ssh.startSession();

Command cmd=    session.exec("/tmp/BenchIT/rs-sysmon/dstat --noupdate -T -c -m -n -d -r --aio -s -g --vm --fs  -i -y -p --disk-util --output /tmp/BenchIT/rs-sysmon/dstat_resultfile.csv 1");

System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());

cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());

session.close();
```

so now the problem is, that the `dstat` process starts on the remote machine and records into a `.csv` file, just as I want it to do, but the Java program waits for the process to finish. so the line after `session.exec()` is never reached.

I also tried to run a local script on the remote server just containing the `dstat` command, but still my program waits for `dstat` to finish, which never happens...

So now my question is: how do I continue with my program while `dstat` runs on the remote machine? and when that is achieved, how do I stop `dstat` after my program finished what it is supposed to do?
Do I need to run separate threads or something? I really don't know how that works...

(the machine running the code is Linux as well)

Comment: Why not using Thread, you can run the instruction in a Thread and you program will continue running.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried using a thread now and it seems to work! At leas the programm doesn't get stuck at the .exec command. But the problem now is: how do I stop the command? Do I need to kill the thread for that ? I got a class called "connection" which implements "thread" now and in which the methods for starting and stopping dstat are implemented. When I try `this.stop();` in the method that shoud stop dstat, eclipse stikes the "stop" out. What does that mean?

Comment: When you stop the Thread it doesn't stop the command look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105861/java-how-to-stop-shell-script-launched-previously-in-the-program

Comment: awesome! that did it for me ! I just used `kill bash` to stop dstat running in background and let the thread the way it was. Probably not the most elegant way - but it works. Thank you very much!